# Закрасить уголок у выделенной ячейки ComboBox основным цветом JavaFX, CSS

Tags: css, javafx

Ни как не получается закрасить уголок у выделенной ячейки ComboBox основным цветом, он остается белым, а надо #2f4f4f

Вот мой код CSS:

```
 .combo-box {   
     -fx-border-color: #000000;
     -fx-border-width: 1;
     -fx-background-radius: 0;
     -fx-background-color: #2f4f4f;
     -fx-font-family: "Arial";
     -fx-font-size: 12px;
     -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
     -fx-background-insets: 0;
     -fx-alignment: center;
     -fx-content-display: center;
 }

 .combo-box > .cell {   
     -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
     -fx-alignment: center;
 }

 .combo-box:hover {   
     -fx-background-color: #87cefa;
 }

 .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell {
     -fx-background-color: #2f4f4f;
     -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
     -fx-text-alignment: center;
 }

 .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected, 
 .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected:hover {
     -fx-background: #2f4f4f;
     -fx-background-color: #87cefa;
     -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
     -fx-text-alignment: center;
 }

 .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:hover {
     -fx-background-color: #87cefa;
     -fx-text-alignment: center;
     -fx-background-radius: 10.0;
 }
```

[image: скриншот]